# LightGBM selection of target for regression (GPU)

Tags: lightgbm

I compiled/installed the GPU variation of LightGBM and I am able to run the regression example.

Now I would like to use another dataset for regression. 
How do I specified which column is the target and which ones are the predictors?

Comment: Which binding (=language) do you use and what interface (python has 2 wrappers)

Comment: Well, in the context of this question: none as I wanted to use the executable through the command line and configuration file.

Although, I tried that because I could not find an easy way to use the GPU version of LightGBM through R.

Comment: if you use the binary directly, then I suppose this is relevant: `Label is the data of first column, and there is no header in the file.` [from the main docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick-Start.html#training-data-format). But using lightgbm from some language is much more comfortable. Did you try setting `device` parameter?

Comment: Cheers! I've been through that line a few time but I was in a "regression"  mindset and didn't realised that by Label it meant the Target...